# Flex Event flows for built-in event and custom event

Tags: apache-flex, event-flow

I hava a custom component and it contains a child icon. If I add a mouse-click event listener to both component(click-listener1) and icon(click-listener2), the event dispatched sequence is click-listener2, then click-listener1. I can understand it. But if I add a custom event to component (listener1), and mouse-click event to icon(listener2), when icon is clicked, the component will dispatch the custom event. In my test, the event dispatched sequence is listener1, then listener2. It doesn't match with event-bubbles rule.

In my opinion The custom event is dispatched in listener2, which triggers listener1. Why event flow sequence is not listener2, listener1?

In component.

```
 icon.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, iconClickHandler);

    private function iconClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
       trace ("Listener2");  
       var customEvent:CustomEvent= new CustomEvent(CustomEvent.CUSTOM_EVENT, true, true);
       dispatchEvent(customEvent)
       trace ("Listener3");  
    }
```

In Application, which contains component

```
 component.addEventListener(CustomEvent.CUSTOM_EVENT, customEventHandler);

private function customEventHandler(event:CustomEvent):void {
   trace ("Listener1");  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPD**

You've got:

```
private function iconClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace("listener2");
    var customEvent:CustomEvent= new CustomEvent(CustomEvent.CUSTOM_EVENT, true, true);
    dispatchEvent(customEvent);
    trace("listener3");
}


private function customEventHandler(event:CustomEvent):void
{
    trace("listener1");
}
```

When `MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICK` is dispatched, it triggers first lucky listener - it is your component function `iconClickHandler`. Here we trace "listener2" and dispatch custom event.

**Due to syncronious nature of events, `CUSTOM_EVENT` listeners are triggered immediatly**, that means that **dispatching an event is similar to calling listener functions**. Events are not stored anywhere, they are not delayed: listeners to events fires immediatly, in the same control flow, in the same thread.

`CUSTOM_EVENT` was dispatched, its listeners were triggered - we've got a call to `customEventHandler` and "listener1" in console.

When all the listeners were triggered, control returns to `iconClickHandler` and "listener3" is traced to console.

That's why we've got output:

```
listener2
listener1
listener3
```

Comment: In fact iconClickHandler is listener2. What confuse me is CUSTOM_EVENT listeners happens earlier than iconClickHandler which dispatch CUSTOM_EVENT

Comment: Check everything once again. Make sure: your trace statements (or how do you check handlers order) are written properly and exlude messing (I mean, before any call to next `dispatchEvent`); your custom event name doesn't match any other event name; your listeners and event have proper bubbling and caption flags;

Comment: Yeah, in iconClickHandler function, dipatched event should be customEvent. I have modified it. I check handler order by flash palyer debuging. The order is customEventHandler, iconClickHandler

Comment: Try the updated code. In what order listener strings are written to console?

Comment: The order is Listener2, listener1, listener3. I don't understand why listener3 is behind listener2.

Comment: I update your codes. It seems the update only visible to me.   > private function iconClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        trace("listener2");
        var customEvent:CustomEvent= new CustomEvent(CustomEvent.CUSTOM_EVENT, true, true);
        dispatchEvent(customEvent);
        trace("listener3");
    }

Comment: I approved your update. Check my answer now, I explained the order.